# how to open a link in the targeted div

Tags: html

I want to show the content of home.html page in the " right_side " div of the page. How can I do that?

link.html-----------------------

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Link Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left_side">
<a href="home.html" >Home</a>
<a href="products.html" >Home</a>
</div>
<div id="right_side">
</div>                                    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like You need to use [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX), [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: There are now numerous answers to this question. Although I'm not a moderator or anything, I'm asking you to please accept the answer that suits you best, _or_ discuss in the comments in order to get to a final answer.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of div  you can simply use iframe.
Just put

```
<iframe name="right_side" src="" width="100%"  
        height="100%" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

In place of your right side div.

and replace `<a href="somelink">` to `<a href="somelink" target="right_side">`

Comment: `ID`s and `name`s share the same namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a dynamic solution:
You could use something like jQuery to retrieve the HTML/DOM of your home.html file, and then insert the relevant DOM-subtree from home.html into the #right_side div.

Otherwise (not dynamic):
Just copy & paste the contents. But that's too trivial, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ajax instead. Write something like this

```
 <a href="javascript: loadXMLDoc();" >Home</a
```

and in your `head` implement that. I added a javascript google jquery location. You must have that "right_side" div in your css. The location of the file `home.html` must be accurate. Check whether it works.

#### loadXMLDoc()

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="[http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js]"></script>
<title>Link Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("right_side").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","home.html",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script></head>
<body>
    <div id="left_side">
        <a href="javascript:loadXMLDoc()" >Home</a>
        <a href="products.html" >Home</a>
    </div>
    <div id="right_side">
    </div>                                    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried ur code but when I click on home..it doesnt show anything

Comment: Try it again with that jquery link.